# Is vcov the information matrix /n from the theory?

Tags: regression, approximation

If I fit a model

```
m <- glm/gam/gamm/lme/whatever(y ~ x + z, family = some exponential family)
```

and extract

```
coef(m)
vcov(m)
```

does it hold true that I can simulate the actual coefficients using

```
MultivariateNormal(coef(m), vcov(m))?
```

I learned a long time ago that the MLE parameters are approximately normally distributed with mean equal to the estimated parameters and variance matrix equal to the informatin matrix divided by $n$.

So, if true, would this mean that vcov is equal to that information matrix, divided by $n$?

Comment: It would be bootstrapping, not simulation, but it would be appropriate

Comment: But will vcov give you the inverse observed information? Close, the inverse information and covariance are the same under the assumption of normality, but they will be estimated slightly differently. $\sigma^2$ will be estimated differently in each situation.

Comment: Hold on a sec, I think I was a little unclear in my last comment.

In theory, the inverse information and the covariance matrix of $\beta$ are the same. But, vcov estimates the least squares estimate of the covariance matrix of $\hat{\beta}$, whereas the way you estimate the information matrix is you plug in the estimates of the MLE into the information form. The LS estimate of $\sigma^2$ is $SSE/(n-p)$ (if you have $p-1$ covariates and an intercept) whereas the MLE estimate of $\sigma^2$ is $SSE/n$. So their estimates will be slightly different.

Comment: In this case, you can you should use the LS estimates because they are unbiased and have the same asymptotic properties as the MLE.

Comment: But under the exponential families not normal, (I am almost certain but not positive) they just use the MLE / Information.